# Firebase database not retrieving data W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -KeAi52QSaiuf7p5jEYM found on class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Database

```
"userinformation": [
    "-KeAi52QSaiuf7p5jEYM" : {
        "website" : "test1"
        "username" : "test1"
    }
}
```

Class myprofile not retrieving data

```
package **.****;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import ****.****.m_Model.useri1;



public class myprofile  extends AppCompatActivity {


    private  TextView myusername111;
   private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase;
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myprofile__activity);




        myusername111 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview22);
        mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

      mFirebaseInstance.getReference("userinformation").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                useri1 model = dataSnapshot.getValue(useri1.class);

             myusername111.setText(model.getusername());


            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }


        });




    }
```

class edit_profile

```
package package ***.****;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import ***.***.m_Model.useri1;




public class edit_profile extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;






    private EditText website;
    private EditText username;
    private Button bsubmit;
    private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase;
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;


    private android.view.ViewGroup parent;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);


        mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("users");
        usernamr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernamr);
        website = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.website);
        Button bsubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_submit);


                bsubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        if (!isEmpty(website, username) && !isEmpty(website, username)) {
                            mNewprofile("53", website.getText().toString().trim(), username.getText().toString().trim());
                           finish();
                           startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), myprofile.class));
                        }
                    }


        } );



    }
    private void mNewprofile(String s, String username, String website) {



        new_profile1 userinformation1 = new new_profile1(website, username);

        mFirebaseDatabase.child("userinformation").setValue(userinformation1);
    }
```

class useri1

```
package **.****.m_Model;



public class useri1 {


    public String username;
    public String website;


    public Update_user1() {
    }
    public Update_user1(String username,String website) {
        this.website = website;
        this.username = username;


    }

    public String getwebsite() {

        return website;
     }

    public String getusername() {

         return username;
     }
    public void setwebsite(String website) {
          this.website = website;

      }
  public void setusermame(String usermame) {
         this.usermame = usermame;

     }
```

Error:

> W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -KeAi52QSaiuf7p5jEYM found on class
>   ***.****.m_Model.useri1

Answer (score 0):

You're retrieving the value of `userinformation`. So the snapshot you get in `onDataChange` will have this value:

```
"-KeAi52QSaiuf7p5jEYM" : {
    "website" : "test1"
    "username" : "test1"
}
```

A `useri1` has a `website` and a `username` property. But in the JSON above, there is only a property named `-KeAi52QSaiuf7p5jEYM`. So the two don't match up, leading to the error you get.

To fix this you should do a few things:

- loop over the children in the snapshot
- drastically simplify your POJO

The resulting code would be:

```
mFirebaseInstance.getReference("userinformation").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            MyUser model = dataSnapshot.getValue(MyUser.class);
            myusername111.setText(model.username);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});

public class MyUser {
    public String username;
    public String website;
}
```

You *could* also use a class with getter and setter. But in that case make sure that the getters follow Java Bean property rules for the capitalization. So:

```
public class MyUser {
    private String username;
    private String website;
    public MyUser() {
    }
    public String getUsername() { return username; }
    public void setUsername(string value) { username = value; }
    public String getWebsite() { return website; }
    public void setWebsite(string value) { website = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ChildEventListener` instead of `ValueEventListener`.

Because you are using `ValueEventListener` Firebase is trying to set a property named `-KeAi52QSaiuf7p5jEYM`, but it is not a property, it is a key.

The code to add `ChildEventListener` looks like:

```
mFirebaseInstance.getReference("userinformation").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousKey) {
            Update_user1 user = dataSnapshot.getValue(Update_user1.class);
            // ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousKey) {
            // ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousKey) {
            // ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // ...
        }
    });
```